# Audio/Video chat in IM

Tags: pidgin

I've recently migrated to Linux Ubuntu 12.04 LTS from Windows. To make this decision successful, I am trying to find solutions to preserve my old internet practices. Instant Messaging is one of them.

Most of my contacts use either MSN/WLM or Yahoo on Windows. Pidgin 2.10.3 (I've installed) on Ubuntu does nice job to gather them just under one roof. But, I don't know if I can audio/video chat with them through it. If yes, how? And if not, which application makes it possible keeping all other facilities (file transfer, emoticons, etc) available?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You can use empathy. Connect head phones, webcam, login to your accounts and simple right click for audio/video chats. If someone calls you, you will be prompted.

Also, skype is available in Linux

Comment: I've a Creative NX webcam and an installation CD with it. I suppose the CD is meant only for installation on Windows. Can I make any use of it for install on Ubuntu? Do I need to install it or Ubuntu will recognize it as soon as I plugin the webcam?

Comment: Technically that's a separate question, which frowned upon by the StackExchange overlords.  Nevertheless, the answer is here: http://www.ideasonboard.org/uvc/